# How to pass array values in JSON?

Tags: java, android, json

```
ArrayList<StylistArray>stylistsArr=new ArrayList<StylistArray>();
stylistsArr.add(new StylistArray("BqYWKWzs4r8SyGQvyqH2","18:30"));
stylistsArr.add(new StylistArray("at5kjx5FqIxbnMys8w4q","18:30"));
stylistsArr.add(new StylistArray("nFI5hxfIePx240dmqR0R","18:00"));
stylistsArr.add(new StylistArray("spxSj8UZem5uD0wL46EP","18:20"));
```

.

```
https://us-central.jshshskajshdala.net?dasa="+"2018-09-04"+"&ewsss="+"17:50"+"&stylist="+String.valueOf(stylistsArr)
```

I want to pass this arrayList along with the url. When I try to pass the array values the name of the model class is passing instead of values in the class

Example
I want to pass values like this:

```
[
  {
    "stylist": "BqYWKWzs4r8SyGQvyqH2",
    "endTime": "18:30"
  },
  {
    "stylist": "at5kjx5FqIxbnMys8w4q",
    "endTime": "18:30"
  },
  {
    "stylist": "nFI5hxfIePx240dmqR0R",
    "endTime": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "stylist": "spxSj8UZem5uD0wL46EP",
    "endTime": "18:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Use for loop , create object in for loop and add it into Json Array list. Create Json Array list outside of for loop

Comment: k i will try this

Comment: You can bundle the request as JsonArray and send through your HTTP POST requests.

to build the JSONArray objects

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Mathan and @Cris say, you can simply using for looping to create your JSON string. For the following simple pojo:

```
public class StylistArray {
  // use a final so the value can't be change once the object is created.
  private final String stylist;
  private final String endTime;

  public StylistArray(String stylist, String endTime) {
    this.stylist = stylist;
    this.endTime = endTime;
  }

  public String getStylist() {
    return stylist;
  }

  public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
  }
}
```

You can simply doing the following:

```
List<StylistArray> list = new ArrayList<>();
// assume you have add all items to the list.

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
try {
  // You need to use simple for loop instead the following foreach
  // because foreach is slower than traditional loop.
  for (StylistArray stylistArray : list) {
    // create JSON object for each item
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("stylist", stylistArray.getStylist());
    jsonObject.put("endTime", stylistArray.getEndTime());

    // append it to your JSON array.
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
  }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  // Error happens, try to handle it.
}
```

Then you can get the string from the `JSONArray`. I'll let you to find out ;)

Comment: k this i got it but how to pass that array with the link

Comment: i want to pass three parameters first and second is string the third one is i want to convert the array into string then i have to pass the paramaters in the given url

Comment: convert the JSONArray to string then append it to your url.

Answer (score 4):

Add the Gson dependency in gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

and rebuild your project

```
String json= new Gson().toJson(stylistsArr);
```

Now your "json" variable will have a json array.

Comment: when i am  using your suggestion the string json contains endTime first stylist second.i want stylist first endTime second

Comment: Although using gson is a valid solution, adding a library may not be the best solution if it's going to be used only for that. Perhaps creating the JSON manually would be better in this case

Comment: @Cris you are right.@Deepa can you share StylistArray class? bqz i think you declared String endTime; and after that String stylist;. Change it to String stylist; and then String endTime;. I hope that will help you.

Comment: private String stylist;
    private String endTime;

    public StylistArray(String stylist, String endTime) {
        this.stylist = stylist;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

Comment: also when i use gson the url and the array is separated.the json string is not along with the url

Comment: String json= new Gson().toJson(stylistsArr);
            Log.e("array",json);

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
                String url= "https://us-central.jshshskajshdala.net?dasa="+"2018-09-04"+"&ewsss="+"17:50"+"&stylist="+json
"

Comment: i am passing parameters like this

Comment: @DeepaDinesh I am not understanding this "also when i use gson the url and the array is separated.the json string is not along with the url" what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();
    maps.put("stylist", "BqYWKWzs4r8SyGQvyqH2");
    maps.put("endTime", "18:30");
    values.add(maps);
    maps.put("stylist", "at5kjx5FqIxbnMys8w4q");
    maps.put("endTime", "18:30");
    values.add(maps);
    maps.put("stylist", "nFI5hxfIePx240dmqR0R");
    maps.put("endTime", "18:00");
    values.add(maps);
    JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(values);
```